# Customize Hybris Backoffice login Theme

Tags: authentication, background, themes, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

Anyone has an idea about how to change the default Backoffice Login Theme (Color, Background and image or any of these) ?

It could be helpful if you point out the file(s) responsible for this, or a specific way to customize it.
Using Hybris 6.0 or later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Replacing Styles of Backoffice Application* :

It is possible to replace the standard look and feel of the Backoffice Application. In other words, you can change the style sheet used in login page and main application pages including all components.

Files responsible for changing Backoffice main page style are located in the following key properties :

```
backoffice.cockpitng.mainpage.css=/cng/css/mainpage_whitelabel.css
backoffice.cockpitng.loginpage.css=/cng/css/loginpage_whitelabel.css
backoffice.cockpitng.overridewidgetsandeditors.css=/cng/css/customWidgetsAndEditors.css
```

For more about this topic, you can visit this [link](https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8be2eefb866910148ccd93a36d650316.html).

Comment: Could you please provide the source link so that I can see more details on how to proceed ?